# Need image to responsively fill responive square area

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, jsfiddle

Here is my jsfiddle code.

```
<div class="gallery-thumbnail">
    <a href="google.com">
        <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/ed/13Vend%C3%A9miaire.jpg/1024px-13Vend%C3%A9miaire.jpg" />
    </a>
</div>

.gallery-thumbnail {
    display: flex;
    max-width: 400px;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: silver;
}
.gallery-thumbnail a { /* This magic makes a square, because the padding % is of the element's width. */
    height: 0;
    padding-bottom: 100%;
}
.gallery-thumbnail img {
  position: relative;
  object-fit: cover;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: green;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/hgw7s9qf/

I spent a while searching around how to make an element square for all screen sizes, and then some more time trying to set a not-perfectly-square image inside that area. I am finding I can't have everything at once.

How can I get that image to fit-fill the square responsively, the way one would expect `object-fit: cover` to work, yet still maintain the area as a dynamically-resizing square?

Important: I need this to be responsive, so the square shrinks as the window does, and the image inside should too.

Comment: Note that just removing `width:100%` from the `img` css doesn't do what I want, because the image needs to be shrunk so its shorter edges just hit the edges of the square, as `object-fit: cover` is supposed to work.

Comment: What does "perfectly square" mean in this context? You answered you're own question, and I'm not sure what the intent was in either circumstance. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: Open up the answer jsfiddle and play with it. As you resize the window, Napoleon remains cropped to a square, and he resizes so the edges of the image fit right inside that changing square. I'm trying to make gallery entries, where I can use not-perfectly-square images for previews.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way.

I am not really sure why it works, exactly. Maybe one of you brilliant people can help with that.

```
.gallery-thumbnail {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    padding-bottom: 100%;
}
.gallery-thumbnail img {
    position:absolute;
    object-fit: cover;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/7f13rnvu/

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! Your answer i finded on eightst page of google search for search string "css square thumbnail site:stackoverflow.com". Your answer is firstest truly applicable in responsive gallery. Great job!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what your end goal is but with the same markup, I got this to work:

```
.gallery-thumbnail {
    max-width: 400px;
    background: red;
}
.gallery-thumbnail img {
  display: block;
  object-fit: cover;
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
}
```

After reading [this](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_object-fit.asp), I think that the image needs both `width` and `height` for `object-fit` to work its magic as it's fitting within the *image* sizing.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but notice that when you run your code, the square doesn't responsively resize. I need it to shrink down as you pull the window smaller, as mine does, yet also contain the image like yours does, yet also resize the image dynamically so it looks like a smaller version of yours as the window shrinks.

It's like having cake and eating it too, and it's frustrating there isn't just a way to set `width: height` in the css and be done with it.

Comment: I was going to comment above on your answer but I haven't enough reputation to do so, so I thought I'd answer here. It works because the height is set on the image (to the parent height), I'd just be careful now setting and testing your responsive sizing using `padding-bottom` to make sure it works in all scenarios and browsers/devices you need; this page might help with that: http://andyshora.com/css-image-container-padding-hack.html. All the best.

Answer (score 0):

To make an image properly square you need to specify same height and width for the image. You can try like this

```
<div class="square">
  <div class="content">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/ed/13Vend%C3%A9miaire.jpg/1024px-13Vend%C3%A9miaire.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
</div>

.square {
    border: 5px solid red;
    text-align: center;
    width: 50vw;
    height: 50vw;
  }

.content {
}
.content img{
  height: 50vw;
  width: 50vw;
}
```

Working Fiddle

[Square Image](https://jsfiddle.net/nayeem629/8j0hcksx/1/)